# Swift 3: UITableViewRowActionStyle() "Missing Parameter" Error Msg

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitableviewrowaction

When I swipe a UITableView cell, the below code is called:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    //Problem code
    let delBut = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle(), title: delete_InLocal) { action, index in
        //Setup
```

Now that I've started migrating to Swift 3, I get an error message on the UITableViewRowActionStyle():

> Missing argument for parameter 'rawValue' in call

Anyone know what the syntax for Swift 3 is in this situation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Default initializers are removed from some imported enum types in Swift 3.

Use `UITableViewRowActionStyle.default` (or in your case simply `.default`) instead of `UITableViewRowActionStyle()`.

```
    let delBut = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: delete_InLocal) { action, index in
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UITableViewRowActionStyle as if its an enum.  If you type it you will see multiple options:

```
UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default
UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive
UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal 

let delBut = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Default, title: delete_InLocal) { action, index in
}
```

Some times only "special" cases are provided in this manner ... and you have to use rawValue: 0  in order to denote default behavior

Comment: as of Xcode 8 beta 6 enumeration cases should start with lowercase letters `UITableViewRowActionStyle.destructive`